# How to avoid UI freezes?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

Im trying to find the best way to avoid having tiny UI lockups after certain events in my app. For example here are two cases where i have come across mini-lockups:

1. I have a button that when pressed loads a local mp3 file (around 20-30mb) using AVAudioPlayer, calls the prepareToPlay method and then plays the audio file. The issue is that the button has the showsTouchWhenHighlighted flag set to yes and after pressing it it stays highlighted until the audio file begins playing which could take 1-3 secs.
2. Another similar example is using a navbar button to sort and reload the table data. There is a very short but noticeable lockup where the button remains highlighted until the table has reloaded.

Can anyone suggest a good approach to minimizing/eliminating these mini lockups? I didnt really come across any code to achieve this in any of the books/tutorials i read that dealt with tableviews and avaudioplayer. Should i be launching these actions on different threads?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For number 1, your best bet is to load the item on a background thread and inform the user that you're doing so (either via a loading HUD or some other indicator).  The simplest way of doing this will be to use `- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg;`.  If you're running iOS 4.0 + you may want to look into executing block callbacks and see if they will work for you.

For number 2, perform the sorting on the background thread or change your sorting method (consider using a sorted data structure rather than resorting after inserts?).  reloadData should occur only on the main thread.

Comment: Regarding iOS 4.0+: Just want to mention that Grand Central Dispatch is what you should look into for doing stuff in the background, among other cool things.

Comment: Grand Central is more for when you want to issue a large number of instances of the same — generally quite lightweight — task. Classic example is doing the stuff inside a for loop in parallel rather than in series. For pushing a single costly task off the main thread, it's not so useful. Ditto for NSOperationQueues, which predate GCD but are now an abstraction for it.

Comment: Good info, haven't really played with GCD much yet (I've been stuck in 3.x land for a while).

Comment: Thx, i think this will def help. Is it possible though to use this method to load a UIWebView in a bg thread? I have a similar issue where selecting a tableRowCell launches a UIWebView in modalViewController. Problem is the tablecell freezes for 1 sec while the [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:] method is executed?

Comment: Just remember that messages to UIKit generally (save for a few instances) must be sent on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an iPhone noob myself, but it sounds like your code is stuck doing synchronous actions, which will guarantee that your UI gets locked up until the action is done executing.

Although I don't have an explicit answer, look for asynchronous options to perform these actions as they will not lockup your UI.  These are usually achieved through using threads or deferred objects.  From my experience so far w/ Objective-C, most actions your program neds to take can be achieved through async actions.